# For loop Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe `df` that has, among others, a column of `groupID`; that is, each observation belongs to a specific group. In total there are 8 groups. I would like to sample from each `groupID` a certain percent of observations (say, 20%). Here is my approach of doing this:

```
val sample_df = for ( i <- Array.range(0,7) ) yield {  
             val sel_df = df.filter($"groupID"===i)  
             sel_df.sample(false,0.2,seed1)  
             }
```

The result of this code is:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = Array([text: string, groupID: int], [text: string, groupID: int])
```

I applied `flatMap()` on `sample_df`, but I got an error:

```
val flat_df = sample_df.flatMap(x => x)
         <console>:59: error: type mismatch;
         found: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
         required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

How can I get a sampled dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanna sample evenly on each group.

```
sample_df.reduceLeft((result, df) => result.unionAll(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, you are trying to get [`RDD`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) of [`Row`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row). For that you can simply call:

```scala
val rows: RDD[Row] = sample_df.rdd
```

To explain the error you get better, flatMap requires something traversable like [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option) but you supplied just a [`Row`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row).

Also, to get all data to the driver, you can call:

```scala
val rows: Array[Row] = sample_df.collect
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, `sample_df` is an array collection of dataframes (`org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`) and `.rdd` method does not work on them. What I need is to flat this array collection to just dataframe. That is why I applied `flatMap` in the first place.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Then Rockie Yang's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you just want to take a 20% sample of the entire dataframe? If so, then there is no reason to create 8 different dataframes and then union them back.

`df.sample(false, 0.2, seed)`

will do the trick. If you want to do different fractions for each groupID then check out `df.stat.sampleBy`. If you want to be sure that there is *exactly* 20% of each class in the sample then you'll have to convert to a PairRDD and use stratified sampling like:

`df.rdd.map(row => (row(groupIDIndex), row)).sampleByKeyExact(false, Map(0 -> 0.2, 1 -> 0.2, ..., 8 -> 0.2), seed)`